# Significado de "Te voy a romper bobo si tu tocas mi minita"

Tags: modismos, diferencias-regionales, español-neutral, significado-en-contexto, vulgaridades

¿Alguien sabe que significa la frase "Te voy a romper bobo si tu tocas mi minita." de la canción de "Jennifer del Estero" de "Illya Kuryaki & The Valderramas"?

Me suena a un vocabulario callejero, maleducado, pícaro pero inventado, con "romper" se referira a "pegar" si tocan a su mujer, o "bobo" es algún tipo de vestimenta?

En el supuesto que sea algo inventado, ¿Es algo vulgar aludiendo a "chichi" que dice un hombre como en "Tengo mi funny pinga for your little chichachicha" o es la respuesta a eso de una mujer? O bien con "minita" se refiere a "falda minita"?(en el caso de que eso exista)

> I'm giving you no chichachicha

> Pendejo, estupido, ay, ay, ay

> Tengo mi funny pinga for your little chichachicha

> Te voy a **romper** bobo si tú tocas mi minita

> Ella viene del estero trayendo su perfume nuevo

> Tengo el vudu sureño, tengo el sendero de tus sueños, sueños
> Jennifer Lopez
> (Na, na, na)

> Tengo mi funny pinga
> For your little chichachicha

> Tengo mi suite stereo
> Tengo mi sacrificio aereo

> Chichachicha baby
> De quince humedos años

> Te mostrare mi mundo
> Tu muéstrame tú hermoso baño

> Jennifer Lopez
> Entro a mi casa
> Abrió la heladera
> Puso su culo junto a la cereza

> De la cual yo comeré
> La próxima primavera
> Yo creo en Dios
> Pero es ella quien cura mis penas

"Romper" sólo lo he escuchado para referirse a maltrato  psicológico, lo que sí he escuchado es "quebrar" en jerga delincuencial, carcelaria o "coa", como en: "No te alumbrís(alumbrarse, jactarse, vanagloriarse o mirar por sobre el hombro) allá adentro(cárcel) o te van a quebrar(golpear duramente, pegar en patota)".

Efectivamente al parecer se usa romper y se deduce por lo explicado anteriormente:

> Mientras uno de los policías le da varios cachetazos en la cara, Marcozzi le tuerce una oreja y luego una tetilla. “¿Por qué no te vas a chorear a tu país?”, le recriminan al presunto ladrón.

> Sobre el final, el comisario mayor comienza a pegarle con un guante de goma de limpieza. “Dale, dale porque te voy a **romper** todo”, le advierte al hombre esposado. De fondo se escucha la risa de uno de los presentes.

> La Jefatura Departamental quedó a cargo del comisario mayor Mariano Laure, que hasta ahora estaba a cargo de la Delegación de Drogas Ilícitas de Mar del Plata.

"Mina" es algo que se dice a espaldas de, de lo contrario puede ser tomado como vulgar, invasivo u ofensivo e igualmente desubicado.

> Así chupamos(bebemos) tranquilos mientras esperamos que aparezca alguna **minita**(pendeja o mujer), hay una sí que me trae bien loco, es la más rica pero no pesca(no toma en cuenta a) a nadie.

> Yo vine y me pegue estaba frontiando

> Y con su **mini** **mini**(minifalda) mataba

> Parece que eso a ella le gusta y eso se le ve

> Le gusta que la guayen y con su mini mata mi mente sonsaca sexoalidad(sexualidad)

> Y hablando claro yo no fantasmie(presumir)

> La pille y no fantasmie te dejaste llevar nena en un dos por tres

> Así es que es correme la maquina ven hazme un strip-tease dale

> Vírame al revés

> Dile que esto es mucha calidad (Parece muy muy buenisima)

> Me seduce y me induce a que la despeluce lentamente

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los Illya juegan muchos con un vocabulario mixto en todas sus canciones. Mezclan palabras en ingles, con español, con spanglish, e inclusive inventan palabras que sonarían mal sonantes, solo a efectos de dejar mejor parada la canción

Por ejemplo en la canción abarájame hay frases como:

> "Abarájame en la bañera" (que en realidad esta hablando de masturbación)

o

> saquéame la dicka sin tu tropa

que no es otra cosa que castellanizar la frase "suck my d*ck" y sin tu tropa, seria sin tu ropa.

En esa frase (y como modismo en Argentina) , la palabra romper alude a tener una pelea a trompadas (y mas específicamente a ganarla).

"Bobo" es un insulto, usado desde los 60, aludiendo a una persona lela o tonta. En general se usaba como insulto contra una persona con una disminución mental.

"Minita" es el diminutivo de "Mina", una mujer.

Traduciendo la frase a un español mas neutro y menos callejero, estaría amenazando a quien ve a su mujer con llevarlo a una pelea.

Comment: Excelente. Español neutro es precisamente.

Comment: Por acá no se usa "romper(sólo psicológicamente tal vez)", lo que sí he escuchado es "quebrar" en jerga delincuencial, carcelaria o "coa", como en: "No te alumbrís(alumbrarse, jactarse, vanagloriarse o mirar por sobre el hombro) allá adentro(cárcel) o te van a quebrar(golpear duramente, pegar en patota)".

Answer (score 0):

---

En la frase

"Te voy a romper bobo si tu toca mi minita"

El significado;

*Te voy hacer daño, (tonto, bobo... es un insulto) si tu tocas a mi minita (se refiere a su novia ó chica)*.

No creo que la palabra "minita" se refiera a un nombre, ya que en Chile por ejemplo se utiliza desde hace más de cincuenta años para indicar que una mujer es atractiva ó guapa. En Argentina es un término más general para mujer, pero también como querida ó prostituta, para otros el mismo nombre de "minita" se refiere a una mujer histérica.

Como nombre y su significado, "Mina" aparece indicando el sentido de pequeña ó mujer pequeña. Por último el significado de "Minita" en Italiano, aparece como "minúscula".

Espero que sirva. Diego M.

Comment: Mina(¡Llegaron las minas!(hombres jóvenes refiriéndose a mujeres jóvenes sin que ellas escuchen ese apelativo), ¡La tremenda mina!(mujer llamativa, despampanante no necesariamente joven y el que lo dice puede no ser necesariamente joven, pero es algo que se dice a espaldas de, de lo contrario es ofensivo y/e invasivo)) en lenguaje informal, callejero, desubicado.

Comment: En Chile también se le dice "mina" a una mujer especialmente joven. Y, por acá no se usa "romper", lo que sí he escuchado es "quebrar" en jerga delincuencial, carcelaria o "coa", como en: "No te alumbrís(alumbrarse, jactarse, vanagloriarse o mirar por sobre el hombro) allá adentro(cárcel) o te van a quebrar(golpear duramente, pegar en patota)". Se usa el prefijo minifalda como diminutivo (falda corta, falda muy pequeña) del latín minimun. "Minita" = "Mini" ("Con su mini mataba")